# How to get devices cl_device_id with OpenCL C++ API

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm begining to use the OpenCL C++ API. I'm been using the C API for long time. The C++ API is a lot more elegant, simple, with less bloated code and less error prone, but I need the devices Ids. In the startup code I'm doing this:

```
vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

//example, get devices from first platform
vector<cl::Device> devices;
platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
```

I need the devices IDs, but don't want to do this with C API:

```
cl_device_id *devicesIds = new cl_device_id[devices.size()];
clGetDeviceIDs(platformsIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, devices.size(), devicesIds, NULL);
```

How can I get de device_id ID from `devs[0]` with the C++ API? Can't find it in the documentation. I see `devices[0]` has the `device_id` value, but I can't get it.

Comment: The C++ API is actually quite terrible (and unidiomatic at best) and seems abandoned. But to answer your question, you can get the device ID by using `operator()`, eg `devices[0]()`. Yeah. Terrible.

Comment: Still it is much better than the plain C. But I agree it could be better, specially in events automatic alloc/release.

Comment: Out of interest - what would be the change you'd like to the way events work? I went through and fixed a lot of other odd design choices when I took over maintenance of the header, nobody had given feedback on events that I could see.

Comment: @Lee Well, I used it in the 1.1 version and it was very painful to call enqueue* functions with events, since it needs event pointers. Therefore needing the user to provide an empty event, and manually deallocate it if it had a useful event inside already. (otherwise it would leak memory)

Comment: Got you. Yes, there were far too many pointer-based interfaces. Take a look at the new header. Within the constraints we had (didn't want to break too much) it should be a lot better. You still have to use operator() to get values out, but it'd be easy to add a .get() or .id() method or similar.

Comment: @Lee Why `enqueueSVMMap()`/`enqueueSVMUnmap()` are missing in cl2.hpp? Coarse grained buffer SVM is mandatory OpenCL2.0 feature which requires mapping. To me these functions should be part of `CommandQueue` same like `enqueueMapBuffer()`/`enqueueUnmapMemObject()`.

Comment: @doqtor That there is precisely why I have wanted to share this code with people willing to review it! Please feel free to file bug reports for things we've missed. Any more discussion let's move elsewhere, this isn't really the point of comments.

Comment: @Lee Can you point me to the place where I can report it? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/ for future reference. Don't worry about this one, I've already added it.

Answer (score 3):

Any of the C++ wrapper objects can return the underlying OpenCL C object using operator().

In the original header the decision was made to make those objects directly convertible to the underlying C objects and I think this simple interface reflects that way of thinking. If you look through the header code of an old version there are many places were arrays of C++ objects are cast directly to arrays of C ids.